# Como fazer um select onde se apresente a ordem "Grupo" depois "Grupos Filhos"

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-express, sql-server-2005

Como é um sistema que contém cadastro de Grupos de Produto. Quero saber como fazer um select que me traga as informações na seguinte ordem dentro do SQL e ordenando tudo por ordem alfabética.

Resumo: Lista um Grupo, depois os Grupos Filhos. Lista o próximo Grupo e abaixo, seus Grupos Filhos.

EX:

- BEBIDAS (seria o Grupo Pai)

- REFRIGERANTES (seria o Grupo Filho);
- ÁGUAS (seria o Grupo Filho);
- CERVEJAS (seria o Grupo Filho);

- LANCHES (seria o Grupo Pai)

- XIS (seria o Grupo Filho);
- CACHORRO QUENTE (seria o Grupo Filho);

Tabela GrupoProduto
coluna grpDescGrupo

Comment: Acho que você precisa postar mais informações sobre a estrutura da sua tabela, entre elas, como é possível identificar os filhos do pai

Comment: Tabela: GrupoProduto
Utilizo as colunas: idGrupoProduto (PK), grpDescGrupo, grpGrupoProdutoPai (FK - do GrupoProduto).

Quero fazer uma query onde eu consiga organizar o conteúdo de dentro dessa tabela.

OBS: organizando tudo em ordem alfabética.

Daí ficaria na primeira linha: BEBIDAS (seria o Grupo Pai)
Na segunda linha: ÁGUAS (seria o Grupo Filho);
Na terceira linha: CERVEJAS (seria o Grupo Filho);
Na quarta linha: REFRIGERANTES (seria o Grupo Filho);

Porém na mesma tabela, tem que também listas os demais grupos e seus filhos também.

Comment: Existe um limite para a quantidade de níveis? Um Grupo Filho pode ser pai?

Comment: Sim, em níveis seria. Pai (Grupo) - Filho (SubGrupo) e no máximo mais um filho (SubGrupo do 1º SubGrupo). Ou seja, terminando no 3º nível.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue uma sugestão para testes utilizando uma CTE recursiva:

```
with CTE_Rec as
(
  select
    idGrupoProduto, 
    grpDescGrupo, 
    grpGrupoProdutoPai,
    cast(grpDescGrupo as varchar(1000)) as DescOrdem
  from GrupoProduto
  where grpGrupoProdutoPai is null
  
  union all
  
  select
    g.idGrupoProduto, 
    g.grpDescGrupo, 
    g.grpGrupoProdutoPai,
    cast(c.grpDescGrupo + '|' + g.grpDescGrupo as varchar(1000))
  from CTE_Rec as c
  inner join GrupoProduto as g
    on g.grpGrupoProdutoPai = c.idGrupoProduto
)

select * from CTE_Rec
order by DescOrdem
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Cara, era exatamente isso. Eu fiz aqui de outro jeito, criando 3 view pra conseguir obter o mesmo resultado. Fiz uma para separar os Grupo Pai, outra para pegar só os filhos e depois juntei, foi trabalhoso, mas também deu certo. Mas era isso mesmo, como estou aprendendo ainda, vim aqui para buscar outras soluções, obrigado !